# UITableView partly deselected when switching to other view

Tags: ios, uitableview

The UITableview's cell is deselected when switching to other view or presenting a segue modally, but height for selected cell is kept.

- Is there a way to keep a cell's selection when switching back and forth between table and detail view?
- Or force the height
  forrow method below to be called?

Problem is when my deselection happens, the cell looses focus. but my height is not reset.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // If our cell is selected, return double height
    ;
    if(self.selectedIndexPath.row==indexPath.row && self.selectedIndexPath!=NULL) {
        return kCellHeight * 2.0;

    }

    // Cell isn't selected so return single height


    return kCellHeight;
}
```

My tableView is housed as a property inside a Simple UIViewController, the view controller is:

```
   @interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

and the property:

```
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a subclass of `UITableViewController` you can set `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` to `NO`.

---

If you aren't, that means you're removing the selection explicitly (sounds like this is your issue) or reloading the table which is resetting the visible cells (but will also redo the heights). You need to stop doing that or ensure that you reapply the selection afterwards.

Comment: I just use delegates: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource and a  @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

Answer (score 0):

The following code forces tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: to be called:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Note that self.tableView does of course work only if you have a UITableViewController. With the simpler UIViewController you'd have to add the tableView as property and IBOutlet.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your self.selectedIndexPath and

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSLog(@"selectedIndexPath : %@",self.selectedIndexPath);
    // If self.selectedIndexPath is nil then put below line in your code.
    self.selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```